# How to compile this test for jdbc connection in python?

Tags: python-3.x, jdbc, compiler-errors, cdata, py4j

I tried using the py4j referred [Connecting and testing a JDBC driver from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353440/connecting-and-testing-a-jdbc-driver-from-python)

```
from py4j.JavaGateway import java_gateway

# Open JVM interface with the JDBC Jar
jdbc_jar_path = 'C:\Program Files\CData\CData JDBC Driver for MongoDB 2019\lib\cdata.jdbc.mongodb.jar'
gateway = java_gateway(classpath=jdbc_jar_path) 

# Load the JDBC Jar
jdbc_class = "cdata.jdbc.mongodb.MongoDBDriver"
gateway.jvm.class.forName(jdbc_class)

# Initiate connection
jdbc_uri = "jdbc:mongodb:Server=127.0.0.1;Port=27017;Database=EmployeeDB;"
con =  gateway.jvm.DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_uri)

# Run a query
sql = "select * from Employees"
stmt = con.createStatement(sql)
rs = stmt.executeQuery()
while rs.next():
    rs.getInt(1)
    rs.getFloat(2)
    .
    .
rs.close()
stmt.close()
```

Getting error as

```
 File "assignment.py", line 9
    gateway.jvm.class.forName(jdbc_class)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
gateway.jvm.class.forName(jdbc_class)
```

with

```
gateway.jvm.Class.forName(jdbc_class)
```

(i.e. capitalise the `c` in `class`.)

`Class.forName` is the Java method you want to call here.  (Note also how the `D` in `DriverManager` is capitalised in `gateway.jvm.DriverManager.getConnection(...)`.)  However, the syntax error is caused because `class` is a Python keyword.  You can't have a local variable, or a function or method, named `class`.

Comment: Now getting below error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py4j.JavaGateway import java_gateway
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py4j.JavaGateway'

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed py4j: https://www.py4j.org/install.html .