# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'java'

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

In my Python notebook in Azure Databricks, the following import statement gives the error shown below. It seems I am missing some package.

What package am I missing, and how can I install it?

**Ref**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63065753/1232087) post. Please note this linked post is using Scala, but I am using Python as I don't know Scala.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
```

Error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'java'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run stored procedure on SQL server from Spark (Databricks) JDBC python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670313/how-to-run-stored-procedure-on-sql-server-from-spark-databricks-jdbc-python)

Comment: `import java.sql.DriverManager` is for Java (and Scala), and implies running on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Comment: Hello, it seems the code you are trying to run is for Scala notebook not Python.

Comment: JPype? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353440/connecting-and-testing-a-jdbc-driver-from-python

Answer (score 0):

There is no `java` package you can install for CPython (with no modifier, Python refers to CPython); Run the code in Jython rather than CPython.

Jython integrates with Java and lets you import packages in Java's `java.*` namespace, such as `java.sql.DriverManager`. See [here](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ModulesPackages/) for more details.